# Do Linux bases operating system provide an API to check the amount of available RAM memory of the system?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, java, c

Let's say that someone wants to write a program that takes a decision based on the amount of available RAM memory that system have.

How can a C++ or JAVA program find out what is the amount of available free RAM.

Comment: Have you tried asking that question to your favorite search engine? I bet you'd get an answer.

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try [SO] but please first read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Specifically asking how to do this in various programming languages makes this off topic. If you want to edit it to bring it in line with our on-topic rules as above then it can be reopened.

Answer (score 3):

Read and parse the file `/proc/meminfo`, it lists both available and free memory. You can do that in any programming language.